# Cómo deshabilitar un Boton por codigo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una MEGA duda:

Resulta que ando  haciendo un formulario web y tengo  dos botones (uno que aumente la cantidad de "boletos" y otro que lo disminuya). Cada vez que la página carga debería mostrar debería mostrar la cantidad de 0.

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:
El botón de disminuir debería estar "bloqueado"  hasta que la cantidad sea mayor a 0 y sí lo hace pero al aumentar no lo  "desbloquea" para dejar que disminuya la cantidad de boletos.

```
    protected void BtnMinus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(lblCantidad.Text);
        Activar_boton();
        Disminuir_cantidad();


    }

    public void Disminuir_cantidad() {
        if (Activar_boton() == true)
        {
            BtnMinus.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Dismiuir_Boletos = Convert.ToSingle(lblCantidad.Text);
            Dismiuir_Boletos--;
            lblCantidad.Text = Dismiuir_Boletos.ToString();
        }
    }
    public bool Activar_boton()
       {
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(lblCantidad.Text);
          if (cantidad == 0)
        {
            return true;

        }else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Nota: lblcantidad: te muestra la cantidad de boletos,
BtnMinus: Es el  botón que disminuye la cantidad de boletos

PD: Si alguien conoce de algún buen curso de C# me lo podrían recomendar, por favor??

Comment: Esto es ASP.net? y como haces el ida y vuelta?

Comment: Sip  esto  es asp.net
Ida y vuelta??

Comment: es que nunca lo estas poniendo en true... donde haces eso?

Answer (score 1):

crea un metodo que al momento de darle un clic al boton "Aumentar" este cheque si el la cantidad es igual a 0, entonces ahi es donde se deberia activar dicho boton de "Disminuir"

```
protected void BotonAumentar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cantidad = Convert.ToInt16(lblCantidad.Text) + 1;
        if(cantidad > 0){
          //aqui activa el boton de disminuir 
          BtnMinus.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, lo  admito, sin embargo  hay un pequeño  detalle si el  botón se bloquea cuando  cantidad sea mayor a cero por qué se bloque cuando la cantidad se igual a -1